# Не срабатывает document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача показать рандомный слайд при загрузке страницы. Почему-то не срабатывает скрипт при закгрузке документа (document.ready) но срабатывает при полной загрузке страницы (window.load), вот скрипт:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  function arrayRandElement(arr) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    return arr[rand];
  }
  var wdth = $('.js-slider-promo').css('width');
  wdth = Number.parseInt(wdth);
  var wdth2 = wdth * 2;
  var wdth3 = wdth * 3;
  var wdth4 = wdth * 4;
  var arr = [wdth, wdth2, wdth3, wdth4];
  var rnd = arrayRandElement(arr);
  var trs = document.getElementsByClassName('v-slider__content');
  $('.v-slider__content').css({
    "transform": "translate3d(" + -rnd + "px,0px,0px)"
  });
});
```

В чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо )

Comment: А js-slider-promo — Это картинки? Должно быть потому что document-ready срабатывает сразу после загрузки HTML, а window-load дожидается, пока не загрузятся все картинки на странице.

Comment: js-slider-promo это блок в котором картинка (img)

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы обращаетесь к свойству `width` картинки, которая еще не загрузилась на странице.
`$(document).ready` - сработает когда будет построено DOM дерево, скрипт попросту не получает свойство width, т.к. по сути его не откуда получить.
По этому мы ждём полной загрузки страницы - `$(window).load` и после этого получаем все свойства

Comment: свойство width прописанно самому элементу DOM: <div class="v-slider__promo js-slider-promo" style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 1100px;" aria-hidden="true">

Comment: Или так документ тоже не видит? Какое тогда решение? Только load?

Comment: что это за слайдер вообще, api слайдера смотрел, может есть методы какие-то ?
Я вот допустим везде использую https://swiperjs.com, в котором документацию читать не перечитать)

Comment: Bx-slider, да но скрипт то написал я сам, вот и хотелось бы понять как сделать моментальный рандомный слайд, щас просто получается так что страница загружается пока, показывается первый слайд из списка и только после полной загрузки страницы(2-3сек) появляется рандомный слайдер, что не есть хорошо...